# How to run install app in internal files dir?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have some lines of code and apk file in internal cache dir:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile(context.getCacheDir() + "/update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I had a parsing error: "There was a problem parsing the package"

Thank You for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third-party apps, including the package installer, have no access rights to that file.

On Android N, [they have finally fixed the problem with installing apps via a `ContentProvider`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205827), like `FileProvider`. For versions prior to that, you can install from [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), or *maybe* use `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` (deprecated, and banned on Android N) to allow that file to be read from [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).